# ¿Cómo ocultar un elemento si existe otro elemento con una clase específica?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo lo siguiente, necesito ocultar lo que contenga la clase precio siempre y cuando la clase prueba exista.

así me funciona pero lo que quiero es me oculte la info de la misma y no oculte la info de los otros que comparten clase.

Como podría hacerlo?

```
<ul class="lista">
    <li class="precio">Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
</ul> 

<ul class="lista">
    <li class="precio">Uno</li>
    <li class="prueba">Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
</ul> 


$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery("li").hasClass("prueba")){
        console.log("prueba");
        $(".precio").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de una manera sencilla, con [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".lista").forEach(el => {
  if (el.querySelector(".prueba")) {
    el.querySelector(".precio").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
    <li class="precio">Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
</ul> 

<ul class="lista">
    <li class="precio">Uno</li>
    <li class="prueba">Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
</ul>
```

Vamos a recorrer cada elemento con la clase `.lista`, el método anteriormente dicho nos da una lista de nodos la cual podremos recorrer con [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), el cual nos dará el elemento con la clase `.lista`, con [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) comprobaremos si existe un elemento `.prueba` dentro de *lista*, de existir, se oculta `.precio`

Answer (score 2):

En tu ejemplo `prueba` esta dentro de un `ul`, por lo que es necesario recorrerlo (Para ir iterando cada `li` y saber si tiene o no la clase `prueba`), para ello utilizamos `.each`.

Ahora, si quieres ocultar el `li` que contiene la clase `precio`, entonces podemos utilizar `hide()` y posteriormente `parent()` para obtener el `ul` referenciado (Porque estamos dentro de una iteracion) para despues ocultar los `li-s` que contiene la clase `precio`, asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lista > li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("prueba")) {
      $(this).parent().find('.precio').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="lista">
  <li class="precio">Uno</li>
  <li>Dos</li>
  <li>Tres</li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista">
  <li class="precio">Uno</li>
  <li class="prueba">Dos</li>
  <li>Tres</li>
</ul>
```

**Referencia**

- https://api.jquery.com/hide/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/parent/